# Having trouble with clear: both:

Tags: css

At this [Test Link](http://www.test.webitry.net) I seek to install header and main site navigation on to the top of a blog script.

My clear:both; worked on the main site script but throws everything to the side now. Have tried numerous fixex without success! Thanks in advance for ant pointers to resolve. Clear:both; is in the footer.

```
/*/////////////////////MAIN SITE NAVIGATION BAR////////////////////*/
.dropnav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #3b3b44;      /*Navigation Active Background*/
    border-top: 1px solid #ccf;
    }
.dropnav ol {
    list-style: none;
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;   
    }
.dropnav li {
    float: left; }
.dropnav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;                  /*Active Text Color*/
    border-right: 1px solid #ccf;
    border-bottom: none;    
    }
.dropnav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 2px solid #ccf; }
.dropnav li a:hover {
    color: #000;                  /*Active Hover Color*/
    background-color: #8db3ff; }  /*Navigation Hover Background*/ 

/*////////////////STYLING TO DROPDOWN MENU//////////////////////*/

.dropnav li ol  {
      display: none; 
      width: 13em; }  /*Define width of dropdown button*/
.dropnav li:hover ol {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0; }
.dropnav li:hover li {
      float: none; }
.dropnav li:hover li a {
      background-color: #3b3b44;      /*Navigation Active Background*/
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccf;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccf;
      border-right: 1px solid #ccf;
      border-left: 1px solid #ccf;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #fff; }                /*Text Color*/
.dropnav li li a:hover {
      color: #000;
      background-color: #8db3ff;  /*Navigation Hover Background*/
}
/*//////////////////END MAIN SITE NAVIGATION////////////////////*/
#container {
    width: 950px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin: 1px auto;
    background: #fafafa;
    }
#header {
    width: 950px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#content {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: `5px;
    }
#footer {
    clear: both;
    background: #3b3b44;
    color: #ccf;    /*text*/
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-top: 2px solid #cc0;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    }
```

Comment: What did you apply clear:both too and what is getting messed up? (Element ids/classes would be nice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two id's with the same name as container. you id needs to be unique and also id fieldset and i guess all your tags are not closed properly very those.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a clear div after you menu to clear out this row. It is the same principle use in the 960 grid sytem.
www.960.gs

But here is a link to see the code and the result.

http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/9x2P3/

Thx